# Recover camera captured image after app was restarted (by the camera itself)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, camera

I'm having a pretty common issue on Ionic with Android (It's also common in Cordova/PhoneGap) where on low ram devices, when you call the camera to get a picture (or any media intent actually), your app goes background and is often closed by the Garbage Collector, and then restarted after the picture was taken.
This is the code I'm using to call the camera, with the ngCordova Camera plugin:

```
var options = {
   quality: 75,
   destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
   //destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
   sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
   allowEdit: true,
   encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
   targetWidth: 200,
   targetHeight: 200,
   popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
   saveToPhotoAlbum: false
};

// This causes the app to go background
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
    // do something with the picture
}, function (err) {
    // do something with the error
});
```

I searched far and wide and there seem to be just 2 posible solutions:

- Implementing your own inApp camera, so your app never goes
  background.
- Saving your app state and restoring it after taking the
  picture.

For multiple reasons, I'm going for the later, saving and restoring my app state, which of course includes retrieving the picture data the camera is returning. After this long context desciption, this is my actual question:

**How can I retrieve the imageData the camera is returning to my app?**

I might be lacking some basic Android knowledge, but I believe the Camera app is returning an Intent to my app, so I tried to recover it with this [WebIntent](https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent) plugin, with no success at all.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, in case anyone is having the same issue, this is what I added in the app.run method:

```
  document.addEventListener('resume', function(evt) {
      if(evt.action === 'resume' && evt.pendingResult) {

            var r = evt.pendingResult;
            if(r.pluginServiceName === 'Camera' && r.pluginStatus === 'OK') {
                var restoredImageData = r.result;
            }
      }
    }, false);
```

Comment: Hi I am having the exact same problem as you, however this solution isn't working for me. My web view is being recreated and I receive a resume event call, however my evt data never contains a pendingResult. So I'm unable to retrieve any image data from the camera. I'm not seeing any errors in logcat and my android 5 device has plenty of memory.